# Print content between first matching brackets

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep

Input example:

```
START{
    some text

    {
      more text}
almost there
}
nothing important{
...
```

Desired output:

```
START{
    some text

    {
      more text}
almost there
}
```

First open bracket could be in different positions:

```
START{...
START {...
START
{...
```

Start could also contain special characters such as: *

I want to print out everything including from START and everything between first matching `{}` (in bash). I was thinking about having a counter that increments when it finds `{` and decrements when it finds `}`. When the result is zero it stops printing out (curly brackets are always matching).

Comment: Can the real text indicated by your placeholders `some text`, `more text`, `almost there`, or `nothing important` include any of `START`, `{`, or `}`? For example if this were a programming lanaguage you were trying to parse then there might be strings (e.g. `"{"` or `"where is START?"`) or comments (`# {` or `// {` or `// not really START`) including any of those but which you would not want to consider when counting.

Comment: No, there is only one `START`, curly brackets can be nested, but they're always in pairs. Of course there could be more text or more brackets.

Comment: If `START` can really be `STA*RT` or similar with regexp metachars or typical delimiters then show **that** as your sample input/output rather than just the sunny-day alphabetic chars case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `pcregrep`:

```
start_word='START'
pcregrep -Mo "(?s)\Q$start_word\E\h*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*+\})" < your-file
```

With `zsh` builtins:

```
set -o rematchpcre
start_word='START'
[[ $(<your-file) =~ "(?s)\Q$start_word\E\h*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*+\})" ]] &&
  print -r -- $MATCH
```

Those use PCRE's recursive regexp feature, where `(?1)` above recalls the regexp in the first `(...)` pair.

If you have neither `pcregrep` nor `zsh`, you can always resort to *the real thing* (`perl`, the `P` in PCRE):

```
perl -l -0777 -sne '
    print $& if /\Q$start_word\E\h*(\{(?:[^{}]++|(?1))*+\})/s
  ' -- -start_word='START' < your-file
```

(note that all but the `perl` one assume the `$start_word` doesn't contain `\E`).

Comment: Your solution does work, it's my fault that I forgot to add some details, such that first `{` could begin in a new line.

Comment: @GeoCap try changing `START` to `START\s*` in the regexp to allow for any optional white space between `START` and `{`.

Comment: @EdMorton, I've now updated it, but used `\h` instead, for *horizontal* spacing only so excluding `\r`/`\n`... To avoid matching on `START<newline>{...}`. @GeoCap, replace with `\s` if that's actually what you want.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I suggested `\s` because GeoCap specifically said in their comment that the `{` could be on the line after `START`: "...first { could begin in a new line.".

Comment: Thanks, my last issue is that START can contain characters that need to be escaped, like STA*RT. I changed the code so I pass in a string /$VAR\s*... is there a way to take the string in literal without needing to write STA\*RT

Comment: @GeoCap [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged but please edit your question to show more truly representative sample input/output instead of adding requirements and other information in comments. FWIW I updated my answer to do a literal string match on `START` instead of a regexp match so it'll work no matter which characters it actually contains (except newline).

Comment: @GeoCap, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

A simple brute force approach that'll work in any awk in any shell on all Unix boxes:

```
$ cat tst.awk
s=index($0,"START") { $0=substr($0,s); f=1 }
f { rec = rec $0 RS }
END {
    len = length(rec)
    for (i=1; i<=len; i++) {
        char = substr(rec,i,1)
        if ( char == "{" ) {
            ++cnt
        }
        else if ( char == "}" ) {
            if ( --cnt == 0 ) {
                print substr(rec,1,i)
                exit
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
START{
    some text

    {
      more text}
almost there
}
```